# Как сделать чтобы бот удалял определенное сообщение, а не удалял из большого текста?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

**Например:** (правильно)

```
Я пишу:  Привет
Бот пишет:  Хай

      (неправильно)

Я пишу:  Я дома Привет
Бот пишет:  Хай
```

**Помогите пожалуйста, а то в интернете вообще найти не могу.**
Мой код:

````
import discord


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Привет'):
        await message.channel.send(f'>>> **_{message.author}_  хотел сказать:**  Хай')
        await message.delete()


client.run('TOKEN_BOT') ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, у вас есть строка `text = 'один два три'`

---

Если вам нужно проверить, начинается ли строка с какого-то определенного слова или другой строки, вы можете проверить это через свойство строки `startswith()`

```
# если text начинается со слова 'один'
if text.startswith('один'):
   # это True, условие выполнится

# если text начинается со слова 'два'
if text.startswith('два'):
    # это False; строка 'два' содержится в text, но text не начинается с нее
```

---

Если вам нужно проверить, является ли строка целиком какой-то другой строкой, например, `'три четыре пять шесть'`, то можно использовать оператор сравнения `==`

```
if text == 'три четыре пять шесть':
    # это False, так как text = 'один два три'
if text == 'один два три':
    # это True, условие выполнится
```

---

Если вам нужно проверить наличие какого-то одного слова в строке (неважно где оно находится), можно использовать оператор `in`

```
if 'два' in text:
    # это True, так как 'два' содержится в text
if 'четыре' in text:
    # это False, 'четыре' не содержится в text
```

---

**Вот исходя из этого выбирайте, какой способ проверки вам нужен и используйте именно его**

Comment: Если честно, то это не работает. Либо я тупой

Comment: покажите условие, которое вы сделали

Comment: Извини, ты лучший все правильно. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Я рад, удачи :)